# I want to pivot wider and spread at the same time but having issues

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

this is an example table that I want to consolidate the data so that each patient is on one row with a different column for each test date/test result.

Each patient has a different number of tests/results and the dataframe looks similar to this.

| Patient ID | test date | test result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Patient 1 | Jan 1 2020 | 100 cps/mL |
| Patient 1 | February 12, 2022 | 49 cps/mL |
| Patient 2 | April 5, 2022 | 99 cps/mL |
| Patient 2 | February 9, 2023 | 29000 cps/mL |
| Patient 2 | August 22, 2021 | 800 cps/mL |
| Patient 3 | December 4, 2022 | 500000 cps/mL |

I want to output look like :

| Patient ID | test date #1 | test result #1 | test date #2 | test result #2 | test date #3 | test result #3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patient 1 | Jan 1 2020 | 100 cps/mL | February 12, 2022 | 49 cps/mL |  |  |
| Patient 2 | April 5, 2022 | 99 cps/mL | February 9, 2023 | 29000 cps/mL | August 22, 2021 | 800 cps/mL |
| Patient 3 | December 4, 2022 | 500000 cps/mL |  |  |  |  |

I've tried a few variations of pivot wider and spread but have been unsuccessful

Answer (score 2):

Using `reshape`. With `ave` we give the data a new *time* variable first, to indicate which dates belong together. Since the variable is called `"time"`, `reshape` will automatically recognize, and we don't have to specify it explicitly.

```
reshape(transform(d, time=ave(Patient.ID, Patient.ID, FUN=seq_along)),
        idvar='Patient.ID', direction='wide')

#   Patient.ID      test.date.1 test.result.1       test.date.2 test.result.2     test.date.3 test.result.3
# 1  Patient 1      Jan 1, 2020    100 cps/mL February 12, 2022     49 cps/mL            <NA>          <NA>
# 3  Patient 2    April 5, 2022     99 cps/mL  February 9, 2023  29000 cps/mL August 22, 2021    800 cps/mL
# 6  Patient 3 December 4, 2022 500000 cps/mL              <NA>          <NA>            <NA>          <NA>
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(Patient.ID = c("Patient 1", "Patient 1", "Patient 2", 
"Patient 2", "Patient 2", "Patient 3"), test.date = c("Jan 1, 2020", 
"February 12, 2022", "April 5, 2022", "February 9, 2023", "August 22, 2021", 
"December 4, 2022"), test.result = c("100 cps/mL", "49 cps/mL", 
"99 cps/mL", "29000 cps/mL", "800 cps/mL", "500000 cps/mL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```